# SQL,PHP: Converting Date Format

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I'm having a bit of a problem where both the SQL function and the php function does not convert dates properly when they're in the format of "DD-MM-YYYY". I am using a mysql database and I want to convert the date to "YYYY-MM-DD" before it is entered into the database.

The SQL function:

```
INSERT INTO lease 
VALUES(3, 4, STR_TO_DATE('22-02-2015', '%Y-%m-%d'),    STR_TO_DATE('27-02-2015', '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Returns as "2022-02-20" and "2027-02-20"

Also, the php function puts the month and day in the wrong place so I have to do "Y-d-m" instead, like so:

```
$startdate = date("Y-d-m", strtotime('27-02-2015'));
$enddate = date("Y-d-m", strtotime('23-02-2015'));
```

Although that stores it correctly. Any date where the day is > 12 will reset the date to"1970-01-01" because it thinks the day is the month.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `format` argument for [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) is the format used for the string argument

So use

```
STR_TO_DATE('22-02-2015', '%d-%m-%Y'),
```

Comment: Wow, you literally answered that in under 2 min.  It took me that long to read it!

Comment: Thank you so much! Rookie mistake by me.